# Inline assembly code, what is ebp?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am having trouble understanding what this does:

```
shr [ebp + 8], 1
```

I get that it shifts the bits to the right, but what the heck is `ebp + 8` doing and/or targeting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EBP is the stack base pointer. Usually when you see something like `ebp + 8` that would be referring to a local variable or a function argument. Typically arguments have positive offsets from `ebp` and local variables have negative offsets.

I suggest you read Matt Pietrek's MSDN article: [Matt's Just Enough Assembly Language to Get By](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0298/hood0298.aspx).

Comment: And the brackets indicate operating on the memory at that location.

Comment: So if ebp + 8 were in a function, would it be targetting the parameter?

Comment: Yes, that would seem most likely. FWIW, all code is inside a function one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

It means whatever is at location `EBP+8` (so 8 bytes higher in memory than `EBP`). Typically, `EBP` is a copy of the stack pointer [aka "Frame pointer", pointing at the "current stack frame] at the beginning of the function, but it's just another register, so it may contain ANYTHING. In fact, code relying on `EBP` having a particular value is generally a bad thing.

When using `EBP` as a frame-pointer, positive offsets means arguments, negative offsets means local variables (as they go on the stack "above" [stack grows towards address zero] the arguments) - you have to also take into account the saving of `EBP` itself at the start of the function [as we need to restore it before returning, so the calling function gets it's `EBP` back to "normal"] and the return address, so `EBP+8` would normally mean the first argument to the function.

`shr` is a shift right, in this case by `1`, so the same as a divide by 2.

Comment: It's the same as dividing by 2 and truncating, right? Like shr on 100 or 101 would be 50?

Comment: Integer divide by 2, yes. And it clears the upper bits, meaning negative numbers become (large) positive numbers.

Comment: Hint: For using (E)BP as an address register the default segment register is SS.